# Python: SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing

Tags: python, json

I am trying to read a dictionary object from an external file and then read it from another file. (The object inside of the file apparently is not a json file even though the file name has a json extension.)

```
import json 
import ast


with open('remeeting_media-get-response.json', 'r') as data:
    s = data.read()
    a = ast.literal_eval(s)
    type(a)
```

However, I am getting the following unknown error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/data/finished/Dashlane/diarization.py", line 8, in <module>
    a = ast.literal_eval(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 49, in literal_eval
    node_or_string = parse(node_or_string, mode='eval')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ast.py", line 37, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
  File "<unknown>", line 0

    ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

This is the sample content from the file:

```
{
  "lines": [
    {
      "duration": 1.8899999999999999,
      "line": "these cop ooh",
      "interval": [
        0.0,
        1.8899999999999999
      ],
      "speaker": "Speaker_2"
    },
    {
      "duration": 5.9500000000000002,
      "line": "[noise] hello [noise]",
      "interval": [
        2.3199999999999998,
        8.2699999999999996
      ],
      "speaker": "Speaker_1"
    },
    {
      "duration": 1.5600000000000001,
      "line": "ooh",
      "interval": [
        2081.6900000000001,
        2083.25
      ],
      "speaker": "Speaker_2"
    }
  ]
}
```

I also tried to load this as a json object and it doesn't recognize it as json.

```
import json 
import ast


with open('remeeting_media-get-response.json', 'r') as data:
    raw = json.load(data)
    print raw
```

See the output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/me/Desktop/data/finished/Dashlane/diarization.py", line 7, in <module>
    raw = json.load(data)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 291, in load
    **kw)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 382, in raw_decode
    raise ValueError("No JSON object could be decoded")
ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded
```

Comment: Please post the contents of `remeeting_media-get-response.json`.

Comment: Why are you using ast to parse a JSON file? Use the actual json module that you imported

Comment: @2ps Just updated!

Comment: @KenY-N Updated with the content!

Comment: @cricket_007 I downloaded a dictionary like object into a json file as i thought it would be a json object.

Comment: It's valid json, just call `json.loads`.

Comment: Or, `json.load(data)` to load the file

Comment: @MarkTolonen I have tried that and it didn't recognize the object. See my updated post.

Comment: @cricket_007 I have tried that and it didn't recognize the object. See my updated post.

Comment: You can verify it http://jsonlint.com

Comment: @cricket_007 because of this error : "ValueError: No JSON object could be decoded"

Comment: You said "sample content from the file".  That is a complete json entry.  Is there more than one?

Comment: @cricket_007 I checked with the website and it's a valid json

Comment: I'm guessing there's something wrong with the encoding of the JSON file

Comment: @MarkTolonen Just one file. There are too many object inside the "line" list so I cut down most of the objects to create a sample.

Comment: Well, you've cut out the problem or are missing important information.  I can save that file and load it with your sample code in Python 2.7 no problem.

Comment: @MarkTolonen I was able to resolve the problem by copy and paste the content to a new file and read the new file. I am not sure why that solved the problem.

Comment: Do a hex compare of the two files yourself, or post a link to the original failing file.

Comment: I just resaved the file with "UTF-8 with BOM" in Notepad++ and it reproduces the issue.  Your original file had a byte order mark.